# I cant understand why my webcam is capturing only one frame (the first one one when webcam is started)

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-code

I wrote a python script(using OpenCV) to start, capture video from my webcam, turn it into grayscale and display the following video. When I compiled it for the first time it worked just fine but after 3rd or 4th compilation, it is stuck to only capturing the first frame when the webcam is started.
here's the code:

```
import numpy 
import cv2 as cv 

cap=cv.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    #capture frame by frame
    ret, frame = cap.read() #cv.VideoCapture(0) aslo returns a boolean true value if read correctly    
    #Operations on the frame 
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #display
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(0) &0xFF: #== ord('q'):
        break

#when everything is done, realse the capture 
cap.realse()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

So, it only shows one frame and exits suddenly, or does it wait for a button press?

If you press any key (except for 'q'), it should get the next frame. 
If you wish that the loop goes on and shows the live feed, change

```
if cv.waitKey(0) &0xFF: #== ord('q'):
        break
```

to

```
if cv.waitKey(1) &0xFF: #== ord('q'):
        break
```

This is because `cv.waitkey(x)` waits for 'x' milliseconds for a key press, but if x is 0, it waits indefinitely until you press a key.

Also, you have a typo, at `cap.release()`